# 2 very similar mysql queries differing only in the OR v/s IN clause are giving different results

Tags: mysql, database

Here are the 2 queries:

```
SELECT DATE(created_date) AS date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM Activity a 
  WHERE (a.columnName = "ABC" || a.columnName = "DEF" || a.columnName = "GHI" || a.columnName = "JKL" 
    || a.columnName = "MNO" || a.columnName = "PQR" || a.columnName = "STU" || a.columnName = "VWX") 
  AND DATE(a.created_date) >= "2016-06-02" GROUP BY date
```

and

```
SELECT DATE(created_date) AS date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM Activity a 
  WHERE a.columnName IN ( "ABC", "DEF", "GHI" "JKL", "MNO", "PQR", 
    "STU", "VWX" ) 
  AND DATE(a.created_date) >= "2016-06-02" GROUP BY date
```

The first one gives me 85 for a particular date, the second one 125 for the same date. I was under the impression that using the `IN` keyword is the same as bunching together `OR` statements, but this seems to be suggesting otherwise. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, was just missing a comma in the IN statement due to line breaks in my IDE.